# Prove or disprove the property about non-zero subspaces of vector space $V$: $L_{1}+L_{2} = L_{1}+L_{3} \implies L_{2}=L_{3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $L_{1}, L_{2} $ and $L_{3}$ be non-zero subspaces of vector space V. Knowing that $L_{1} \cap L_{2} = L_{1} \cap L_{3}= \{0\}$ prove or disprove the following statement:
> $$L_{1}+L_{2} = L_{1}+L_{3} \implies L_{2}=L_{3}$$

Hey!
I am learning Algebra just as an interesting past-time activity and ran into this problem. Unfortunately I managed to think myself stuck with this one, so maybe someone can provide me some tips and tricks about how should one approach it....

Comment: Broad hint: consider the case where $L_1+L_2=V$. How can that happen? Can you see multiple ways of doing that? Taking $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ as a concrete choice might help the visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\Bbb R^2$ as $\Bbb R$-vector space and its standard basis. Take $L_1=<(1,0)>, L_2=<(0,1)>, L_3=<(1,1)>$.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

$$\begin{cases}L_1=\{(x,x)\;|\;x\in\Bbb R\}\\{}\\
L_2=\{(x,0)\;|\;x\in\Bbb R\}\\{}\\
L_3=\{(0,x)\;|\;x\in\Bbb R\}\end{cases}\;\;\;\le \Bbb R^2$$